# From where can I download BlowFish.BlowfishNET.dll?

Tags: vb.net

How can I find this dll file? I need it for my graduate project.

I'm working on encrypting/decrypting tool for a streams/file(s), any guidance?

Comment: did you ask Google ??

Comment: Your first question is answered by a trivial Google search.  Your second question is too vague.  Put some thought into what you want to do, and ask a specific question in another post.

Comment: Vote to close as request for resources and/or too broad.

Answer (score 4):

[First hit on Google](http://www.hotpixel.net/software.html#blowfishnet).

The download includes both a demo app and a test project, which should help you with part 2 of your questions. If you have a specific problem with encryption and decryption, you should ask a specific question.